# Using Ling to Sql, merge two queries into one, then get the int value of the result

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq To Sql queries

```
var group = "T";
var categoryQuery = from m
                    in ctx.Material
                    where m.Group == group
                    select m;

var maxValue = from c
               in categoryQuery
               where c.Order == categoryQuery.Select(o => o.Order).Max()
               select c.Order;
```

Where `Group` is a string value (ex: "T", "S", "R") and `Order` is an int value. What I want to achieve is to get the highest `Order` int value from the row in the result set filtered by a particular `Group` value. Ultimately, I want to use the max value for comparison elsewhere in the code, but I'm having trouble accessing the value from the `maxValue` IQueryable object.

So a sample from the `categoryQuery` set would look like this:

```
Id     Group   Order
-----  -----   -----
100    T       0
101    T       1
102    T       2
103    T       3
```

So in the second `maxValue` query, I'd want the 3, because it is the max `Order` value out of all of the T `Group` values.

First question: How can I access the int value in `maxValue`?

Second question: How can I simplify my queries into a single query?

Thank you

Comment: It will result in one query eventually. Did you take a look at the query which is generated? [datacontext.log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your `maxValue` query is just going to be a collection of the maximum `Order` in `categoryQuery` repeated 0 or more times.  What exactly are you attempting to do?  Can you show some example data and the results you want to get?

Comment: Added some sample data to try to clarify the question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to as simple as ordering by `Order`, descending, and then take the first item:

```
var group = "T";
var maxValue = (from m
               in ctx.Material
               where m.Group == group
               orderby m.Order descending
               select m).FirstOrDefault();
```